# Не работает Environment.NewLine в Mono

Tags: c#, linux, .net, winforms, mono

Наступил на грабли. Использую RichTextBox в приложение на WindowsForms, которое в дальнейшем запускаю на Ubuntu коммандой mono TestApp.exe, приложение запускается и выполнят практически весь функционал кроме новой строки в RichTextBox. Так вот, под Windows текст переносится на новую строку, а в линуксе текст идет в строчку через большой промежуток...

```
rtbTest.AppendText(_text.Status + Environment.NewLine);
```

Пробовал

> "\r\n"

Безрезультатно. Возможно кто-нибудь сталкивался с данной проблемой.

Comment: Пробовали \n без \r? В линуксе другой тип оканчивания строк

Comment: Да, пробовал. Не помогает, пробовал и так - ` rtbTest.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi" + @"{_text.Status} \par\r\n" + "}";` Все равно все в одну строку. RichTextBox в свойствах Multiline стоит - true.